# How do I capture the URL of a text in Excel so it can be dumped into SQL (using SSIS)?

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, ssis

I have an Excel file.

```
Column1
Backwater - 01
Backwater - 09
...
```

The name "Backwater - 01" is a hyperlink. I have a SSIS package that gets the Excel data into SQL.

The problem is that for `Column1`, it goes into the table in SQL as "Backwater - 01" and NOT the actual URL: "http...".

How would I approach this?

Comment: Do **all** the cells in `Column1` contain hyperlinks, or just the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to extract the url from the cell. http://howtouseexcel.net/how-to-extract-a-url-from-a-hyperlink-on-excel

If you dont have access to changing the SSIS application that fetches this data, you can use the above example to create a new row of these values that just has the URL, not the hyperlink.  If you need help with that, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand from what you have posted, but I'm guessing you are not accessing the rows in your Excel column by the correct index.

If Row[n] is **Column1**, then Row[n+1] would be **Backwater-01**.

Indexes are zero based, not 1 based.